# Angular callback not enabling button

Tags: angular

I have a callback function setting a component attribute and then enabling the form submit button (via the `submitEnabled` attribute.

```
window.onCaptchaOk = (data) => {
  this.captchaResponse = data;
  this.submitedEnabled = true;
  console.log(`after = ${this.captchaResponse}`);
};
```

However, the button seems to ignore the status change and remain disabled. Any clue why is not working?

Comment: Can you add the form html to the code too

Comment: The callback probably doesn't run in the Angular zone. Try: `(data) => { this.ngZone.run(() => { this.captchaResponse = data; ... }); }` (after injecting `private ngZone: NgZone` in the constructor).

Comment: Do you see your console log ? If so, this might come from the fact that this code is ran outside of Angular's Zone, [see the doc](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) for more info

Comment: Wow, `ngZone` does trick! thanks @ConnorsFan!